# Transporting monoidal structure along adjunction

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories

Let $L: \mathcal C \leftrightarrows \mathcal D : R$ be an adjoint pair and $\mathcal C = (\mathcal C,\otimes)$ be a monoidal category. I wonder under what conditions on the pair $L\dashv R$ we can transfer the monoidal structure to $\mathcal D$, so the adjunction becomes monoidal (not neccessary in the strong sense). What are the relevant references here that I can read?

So for $x,\ y, \ z \in \mathcal D$ we can consider something like $x\square y = R(Lx\otimes Ly)$, but then we need to agree all the triples like $(x \square y)\square z$, $x \square (y \square z)$ etc. If the adjoint pair is an equivalence then it is ok, but perhaps there are other weaker conditions.

Comment: if $R$ is fully faithful equivalently, $L$ is a localization, or the co-unit $LR\to id$ is an isomorphism), and you have the following condition: "if $L(x\to y)$ is an isomorphism, then so is $L(x\otimes z\to y\otimes z)$ for all $z$", then you can do it. Is that the type of condition you're looking for ? Or are you also trying to get away from the fully faithful case

Comment: @MaximeRamzi , for my applications fully faithful is too much, but faithful should be ok. I have an impression that there should be a general theory for answering such questions, which I'm just not aware about.

Comment: I'm not sure, but if $R$ is faithful then maybe your adjunction is monadic, or close to being so. For monadic adjunctions, there are some things you can say if the monad is *strong*, which should translate to some conditions on the adjunction. You could imagine a situation similar to Sets and abelian groups

Comment: @MaximeRamzi could you provide a reference for the criterion posted in the first comment (when R is fully faithful)? Thanks!

Comment: @W.Rether : I'm not sure, it seems like there is Brian Day's "Note on monoidal localizations", and there is also something in Lurie's Higher Algebra in the context of $\infty$-categories

Comment: Thanks! In case you come out with a more specific reference in Lurie please let me know!

Comment: @W.Rether I guess that would be 4.1.7.4. for localizations + the fact that an adjunction in which the right adjoint is fully faithful is a localization, and maybe you would also benefit from 7.3.2.7. after having 4.1.7.4